# Get 5 most common delimited substrings across a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet with substrings inside each cell, delimited by `#`. For example:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F #G #H #I #J #K #L | M#N#O#P | A#B#C#D #E |
| F #G #H #I | N#O#P | A#B#C##E |

How can I find the 5 most common substrings over the range of cells?

Expected output for the sample data should look like this:

| Substring | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| E | 2 |
| F | 2 |

Comment: @Harun24HR It's not returning a count for the individual cell; it's returning a count across the range. Adn eventually I want to paste it as a new worksheet.

Comment: So what would be the desired outcome here?

Comment: @JvdV Each cell contains a set of substrings, delimited by `#`; and I want to know the most common substrings. Could you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I'd like to know what exactly your desired output looks like so I can try to replicate it. See [ask] a quesiton with an [mcve].

Comment: @JvdV Could you clarify why you're asking?

Comment: Sure, it's an interesting question, but it was very minimal. Now you have added some info helping people see/understand exactly what you are after. Would you be interested in a formula solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229336/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-jvdv).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a disconnected [**ADODB.Recordset**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-object-ado) to hold the count of each substring. Then, sort the recordset by the count in descending order, get only the top 5 rows into an array, and paste the array into another Excel worksheet.

The benefits of using a recordset here are:

- **Trivial sorting** -- set the [**Sort**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/sort-property-ado) property

  If the data didn't need sorting (i.e. if I just wanted the counts of the substrings), I would have gone with a [**Scripting.Dictionary**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) instead of a recordset.
- **Easy conversion to an array** using the [**GetRows** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/getrows-method-ado), which can then be used to populate an Excel [**Range** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) using its' [**Value** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value).

  Ideally I'd use the Excel [**Range.CopyFromRecordset** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset), which wouldn't need transposing; but I didn't find any way to limit the number of records in a recordset, or to create a duplicate with only the specified number of records.

Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library**; use the latest version (generally 6.1).

Then, you could write code like the following:

```vb
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Fields.Append "Substring", adVarChar, 100
rs.Fields.Append "Count", adInteger, 5
rs.Open

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Worksheets("Input")

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In sheet.UsedRange.Cells
    Dim substrings() As String
    substrings = Split(cell.Value, "#")
    
    Dim substring As Variant
    For Each substring In substrings
        substring = Trim(substring) ' remove spaces before and after substring
        If Len(substring) > 0 Then  ' ignore empty substrings
            rs.Find "Substring = '" & Replace(substring, "'", "''") & "'"
            If rs.EOF Or rs.BOF Then ' substring might not have been found, or the recordset is empty
                rs.AddNew Array("Substring", "Count"), Array(substring, 1)
                rs.Update
            Else
                rs.Update "Count", rs("Count") + 1
            End If
            rs.MoveFirst
        End If
    Next
Next

rs.Sort = "Count DESC, Substring"

Set sheet = Worksheets("Output")
sheet.Range("A1:B5").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rs.GetRows(5))
```

Note that you could also generate a long string from the data, using the recordset's **GetString** method.

---

References:

- [Excel **Range** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))

  - [**Cells**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells),  [**Value**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) properties
  - [**CopyFromRecordset**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset) method
- [ADODB **Recordset** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-object-ado)

  - [**Find**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/find-method-ado), [**AddNew**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/addnew-method-ado), [**Update**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/update-method-ado), [**MoveFirst**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-ado) methods
  - [**BOF** / **EOF**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/bof-eof-properties-ado), [**Sort**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/sort-property-ado) properties
- [**Scripting.Dictionary** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object)

Answer (score 5):

If one has access to Microsoft365's `LET()` function, this could be done using a combination of functions:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=LET(X,SORT(TRIM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("#",,A1:C2),"#","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.!='']"))),INDEX(SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(X),MMULT(--(UNIQUE(X)=TRANSPOSE(X)),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X),,,0))),2,-1),{1;2;3;4;5},{1,2}))
```

---

**Explanation:**

[`LET()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) allows the use of re-usable variables inside a formula. So in the above we assigned an array of values and named it "X". The array is pulled by:

```
=SORT(TRIM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("#",,A1:C2),"#","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.!='']")))
```

Where:

- `"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("#",,A1:C2),"#","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"` - Is used to create a valid XML-string and;
- `"//s[.!='']"` - A valid xpath to retrieve all non-empty strings.
- `TRIM()` will delete any leading and trailing spaces. `SORT()` then sorts the array ascending.

If you want to know more about this mechanic to "split" a string into elements using `FILTERXML()`, you can have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194).

Now we have a variable, we can use it in the third parameter inside `LET()`:

```
=INDEX(SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(X),MMULT(--(UNIQUE(X)=TRANSPOSE(X)),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X),,,0))),2,-1),{1,2,3,4,5},{1;2})
```

Using `INDEX()` we can "slice" rows/columns from an array, where:

- `SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(X),MMULT(--(UNIQUE(X)=TRANSPOSE(X)),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X),,,0))),2,-1)` - A bit of a complicated construct, but the idea here is that `CHOOSE({1,2}` allows for a 2D-array where the 1st column is filled with `UNIQUE()` values from "X" and the 2nd is the count of each unique element in the total array. The count is done using `MMULT()` where each unique element is counted against the `TRANSPOSE()`'d "X". Then the 2d-array is sorted on the 2nd column.

With the above out of the way, we can simply use `INDEX()` to retrieve the 5 rows we need (and both columns) using:

```
=INDEX(<TheAbove>,{1;2;3;4;5},{1,2})
```

Comment: Could you add some description of the different pieces you're using in your answer?

Comment: @ZevSpitz, see the edit. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, much better. I would note that for me personally, as long as I have access to a programming environment (VBA or Javascript) I probably wouldn't use this technique, as I think it doesn't clearly represent what it's trying to do.